# How to store ZoneDateTime in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, timestamp

I am trying to save "2021-10-25T12:41:21.294+0000" in mysql as ZoneDateTime but not able to save it since mysql doesn't supports ZoneDateTime . Is there any way in MySQL with casting etc? Tried saving in TimeStamp format but getting data truncation error.